# PYTHON: =[WinError 10035] A non-blocking socket operation could not

Tags: python

I cant fix this error, I tried averything and looked everywhere and still cant do it. I think it is the setblocking but have no idea what to do. Ive been at this for hours, please help as it is an assignment for tomorrow

the exact error is: Error while reading: [WinError 10035] A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately.

so its from line 52 in client as an exception?

Client code:

```
import socket
import errno
import sys

HEADER_LEN= 10
IP="127.0.0.1"
PORT= 1337

yourUsername= input("Username: ")
s= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((IP, PORT))
s.setblocking(False)

username= yourUsername.encode("utf-8")
usernameHeader= f"{len(username):<{HEADER_LEN}}".encode("utf-8")
s.send(usernameHeader + username)

while True:
   mess= input(f"{yourUsername}> ")
   if mess:
       mess= mess.encode("utf-8")
       messHeader= f"{len(mess):<{HEADER_LEN}}".encode("utf-8")
       s.send(messHeader + mess)

   try:
       while True:
           usernameHeader= s.recv(HEADER_LEN)
           if not len(usernameHeader):
               print("Connection has been closed by the server")
               sys.exit()


           usernameLen= int(usernameHeader.decode("utf-8").strip())
           username= s.recv(usernameLen).decode("utf-8")

           messHeader= s.recv(HEADER_LEN)
           messLen= int(messHeader.decode("utf-8").strip())
           message= s.recv(usernameLen).decode("utf-8")

           print(f"{username} > {message}")


   except IOError as e:
       if e.errno != errno.EAGAIN or e.errno != errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
           print("Error while reading: {}".format(str(e)))
           sys.exit()

       continue


   except Exception as e:
       print("Error while reading: ".format(str(e)))
       sys.exit()
```

```
import socket
import select

HEADER_LEN= 10
IP= "127.0.0.1"
PORT= 1337

s= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
#AF_INET is for ipv4, SOCK_STREAM is for TCP
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
#allows to reconnect
s.bind((IP, PORT))
s.listen()


socketList= [s]
clientList= {}
print(f"Searching for users on {IP}:{PORT}...")

def receiveMessage(clientSocket):
    try:
        messageHeader= clientSocket.recv(HEADER_LEN)

        if not len(messageHeader): #if we didnt reveive data
            return False

        messageLength= int(messageHeader.decode("utf-8").strip())

        return {"header": messageHeader, "data": clientSocket.recv(messageLength)}


    except:
        return False


while True:

    readSockets, empty, exceptionSockets = select.select(socketList, [], socketList,)
#This has a read list, write list and error list
    for notifiedSocket in readSockets:
        if notifiedSocket == s:
            clientSocket, clientAddress = s.accept()

            user= receiveMessage(clientSocket)
            if user is False:   #someone disconnects
                continue
            socketList.append(clientSocket)
            clientList[clientSocket]= user
            print(f"New connection: {clientAddress[0]}:{clientAddress[1]} username: {user['data'].decode('utf-8')}")

        else:
            message= receiveMessage(notifiedSocket)

            if message is False:
                print(f"{clientList[notifiedSocket]['data'].decode('utf-8')} has disconnected")
                socketList.remove(notifiedSocket)
                del clientList[notifiedSocket]
                continue

            user= clientList[notifiedSocket]
            print(f"Message from {user['data'].decode('utf-8')}: {message['data'].decode('utf-8')}")

            for clientSocket in clientList:
                if clientSocket != notifiedSocket:
                    clientSocket.send(user['header']+ user['data']+ message['header']+ message['data'])

    for notifiedSocket in exceptionSockets:
        socList.remove(notifiedSocket)
        del clientList[notifiedSocket]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the stack trace containing the exact error message, and indicate which line it corresponds to, if it is not obvious.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you could remove try/except for the moment to see more information about error.

Comment: Sorry I dont uderstand what you mean, im using pycharm and the only thing that shows up is what i wrote in the description.